# How to implement lazyloading for creating thumbnail of a video in iOS

Tags: iphone

How to download thumbnail image from the video URL and display it in tableview cell using lazy loading?

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good tutorial for this, provided by apple. You can get it on the below link.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

another link for the same is

http://code4app.net/ios/Lazy-Table-Images/4f8cc55506f6e7d565000001

Comment: If thats what you were looking for then You should mark this as correct answer, not the vote up if you want some thing else then mention here in comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking is a very good choice for a third party library to drop into your project. Very easy to use. Look for UIImageView+AFNetworking in particular.

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking